# Gecko web browser does not load bootstrap

Tags: c#, gecko

When i try to browse a submit page with gecko that use bootstrap to validate fields it doesnot work and when i click submit button it pass all the required field and go to next web page displaying a white blank page.

is there any recommended thoughts to do?

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: Hello, you can try another browser, Chrome is the best one.